# Suppressing Booleans on Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, boolean

Simple question, yet i haven't found the answer.

Anybody here know how to suppress a boolean field from displaying a "False" ?

For example in my report, I have fields that say True or False...i'd rather just see a True and have crystal reports suppress the "False"

Anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Suppress formula for that field (available by clicking the X+1 button on the field object's properties dialog next to Suppress), and make it say :

```
NOT {FieldValue}
```

This will suppress the field if it is False and show it if it is True.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a formula for your field.  The formula would look something like this:

`if {yourfieldname} then "True" else " "`

**UPDATE:**
It doesn't matter if you already have a formula.  Just do this instead:

```
if {field1} = true OR {field2} = true OR {field3} = true then "True" else " "
```

Also, if {field1} is a boolean, then writing

```
if {field1}
```

is easier and more clear than writing

```
if {field1} = true
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this before, and i apologize.  Currently i have a formula that does an "OR" for my requirements.  (Ex:  {Reservations.NY IT Services/Laptop} = true OR {Reservations.NY IT Services/Tablet PC} = true OR ... etc.)  b/c of that formula, i am unable to add anything else :(